# How to make screen -R attach to the youngest detached session?

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on debian lenny, and I would like to use the `-R` option. From `man screen`:

```
   -R   attempts  to  resume  the  youngest  (in  terms  of creation time)
        detached screen session it finds.  If successful, all  other  com‐
        mand-line  options  are  ignored.   If no detached session exists,
        starts a new session using the specified options, just  as  if  -R
        had  not been specified.
```

However, when I run `screen -R` it does not actually attach to the youngest detached session. Instead, it complains that there are "several suitable screens" and that I need to choose one of them.

Am I missing something? How do I make this work as advertised?

Comment: `Note: Time-based session selection is a Debian addition.` ==> are you using the default `screen` from Debian or did you compile one yourself?

Comment: @Jan Claeys: I first tried the Debian lenny binary, then building screen from the latest source at git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git. The behaviour was the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using `screen -RR`.

Example:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    5958.pts-3.sys01    (08/26/2010 11:40:43 PM)    (Detached)
    5850.pts-1.sys01    (08/26/2010 11:40:35 PM)    (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-sdn.
```

Note that screen 5958 is the youngest. Using `screen -RR` connects to screen 5958. The `-RR` options is somewhat further explained in the documentation for `-d -RR`.

```
   -d -RR  Reattach a session and if necessary detach or  create  it.  Use
           the first session if more than one session is available.
```

Another trick I often use is to use `-S` to give the screen a tag/label. Then you can reattach using that tag without having to remember what was happening in each screen if the list gets unwieldy.

Example (Launch screens for vim and curl):

```
$ screen -dm -S curl
$ screen -dm -S vim 
$ screen -list

There are screens on:  
    11292.vim       (08/27/2010 12:02:53 AM)        (Detached)
    11273.curl      (08/27/2010 12:01:42 AM)        (Detached)
```

*Note: The `-dm` option was just used to start a detached screen*

And then, at a later date, you can easily reconnect using the tag `curl`.

```
# screen -R curl
```

Comment: Isn't `screen -D -RR` better than `screen -d -RR`?

Comment: To save some time on the shift key, `screen -rr` works, too.

Answer (score 0):

I use screen -R in gnome-terminal and, as you said, if 2 sessions are running at the same time, then gnome-terminal quits immediately.

I solved it by running

```
sh -c "screen -R || screen -D -RR"
```

this works just as you expect.

Comment: or simply "screen -RR" as suggested by David :D