# How to configure GNU screen or tmux to reattach to the previous session without using command line arguments?

Tags: configuration, login, tmux, gnu-screen

By launching [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/screen.html) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) as the initial default shell ([set with chsh, for instance](https://www.tecmint.com/change-a-users-default-shell-in-linux/)), passing arguments seems not to be supported, such as ["-d RR" for screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/how-to-make-screen-r-attach-to-the-youngest-detached-session) and ["attach" for tmux](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/persistent-terminal-sessions-with-tmux/). [chsh's argument is the full pathname to a shell file executable](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/chsh.htm) (listed in `/etc/shells`).

For screen, is there an internal command to reattach itself to a previous screen session? Or is there a way to *pull* the individual processes from the previous screen session into the current session?

For tmux, is there a way to set, in the user configuration file (`~/.tmux.conf` by default), an option to go directly to the previous session?

After launching tmux without any arguments (which creates a new session), one can manually switch to the previous session (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>(</kbd>) and then kill the newly launched session (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, `:kill-session -a`).

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea. I'd create a wrapper, say `/bin/my-screen` that would look
like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

screen -d -RR
```

Make it executable and add it to `/etc/shells`:

```
echo /bin/my-screen | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

Make it the default shell:

```
chsh --shell /bin/my-screen
```

Notice that some terminal emulators such as `xterm` do not run shell
defined in `/etc/passwd` by default but they check `$SHELL` variable
first.

You can try adding this to your `~/.screenrc`:

```
screen -X screen -d -RR
```

Notice however that there is a potential problem with that solution -
you won't be able to start `screen` at all if there are no existing
sessions `screen` could re-attach. That means that if you set your
`screen` as your default shell you won't be able to log into your
system.

Comment: That's a great workaround, @Arkadiusz, thanks for adding it. I'm still looking for something that could be done if you don't have administrative privileges to the system in question.

Comment: So how did you use `chsh` to make screen your default shell without root?

Comment: `chsh -s /usr/bin/screen <login>` . In the chsh man page:
"A normal user may only change the login shell for her own account; the superuser may change the login shell for any account."

Comment: Ah, ok I see. Sorry for the confusion. So the problem is that you cannot modify local `/etc/shells`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, @Arkadiusz.

Comment: @PedroPalhoto: see updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97557/discussion-between-pedro-palhoto-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).

Answer (score 0):

I have this at the bottom of my zshrc:

```
[ -z "$TMUX" ] && {
    tmux attach || tmux new-session
}
```

Haven't had any trouble so far; been there for years on thar particular server I think

Comment: This mechanism works well for when you start your login with a regular shell. Still looking for a way to do so when screen or tmux are launched directly as the login shell (configured in `/etc/shells`).

Comment: What's the difference, functionally, between what I did and directly launching it as the login shell?  (Even if you managed it, I think it would cripple things like rsync, scp, etc., and restrict you to interactive logins only.  This is of course just a guess).

Comment: For the current use case, crippled protocols are not an issue. The objective was to reduce the number of launched processes to a minimum (there is a FG/BG process quota per user). I find it curious there isn't a configurable way (that I could find about so far) that could attach the previous multiterm session after the screen/tmux session has been launched without command line arguments. Perhaps screen/tmux authors never considered the possibility of command line arguments being unavailable. Knowing how to do so could be useful for some other use case besides the one I stumbled upon.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can replace "tmux" in my suggestion with "exec tmux" and that will achieve what you want.  As for the latter part of your comment, while I can't speak for tmux/screen authors, I have to say your constraints appear to be somewhat unusual so I am not at all surprised.